# Python Type Annotations: Subclass method with annotation referencing subclass of super annotation

Tags: python, type-hinting, covariance

I have two classes

```
class A:
    ...

class B(A):
    ...
```

I have two more classes which utilise these

```
class C:
    def foo(self) -> list[type[A]]: ...
    
class D(C):
    def foo(self) -> list[type[B]]: ...
```

This gives me a type hint error, complaining that the annotation of `D.foo` is not compatible with `C.foo`. It is necessary that `D.foo` declares that it returns list of `B` as `B` contains some attributes not necessarily belonging to `A`.

I read about covariance and contravariance in Python and it seemed like defining a covariant type as follows may help solve the issue

```
T = TypeVar('T', bound=A, covariant=True)


class C:
    def foo(self) -> list[T]: ...
    
class D(C):
    def foo(self) -> list[type[B]]: ...
```

However, the issue persists - mypy still complains that `D.foo` is incompatible with `C.foo`.

Does anyone know of a way to solve this issue?

Comment: Something like [this](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=59828a277835c0ade762168bb66f6784)?

Comment: @STerliakov thank you. I hadn't learned about generics yet, seems like they're the way to go.